# Return data even if the foreign key is null in HQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, hql

I have a `Product` Table that joins a `ProductCategory` table with `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` relations.
`Product` :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private ProductCategory productCategory;
```

`Category` :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="productCategory" ,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JsonBackReference
@OrderBy("id desc")
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();
```

I have this repository method that retrieves data from `Product` table:

```
@Query("SELECT p from Product p where cast(p.id as string) like :x or p.name like :x or p.description like :x or p.sku like :x or p.productCategory.name like :x")
public Page<Product> search(@Param("x") String keyword, Pageable pageable);
```

This method does not return the products where their categories is null.
How to retrieve the products even if I have null on the `productCategory` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with adding (indeed) a `LEFT JOIN` to the query :

```
"SELECT p from Product p left join p.productCategory where cast(p.id as string) like :x or p.name like :x or p.description like :x or p.sku like :x or p.productCategory.name like :x"
```